# template <> use in specializing member functions

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I was messing with specializations to see what would compile with the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
struct base {
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
};
template<> //doesn't seem to do anything here
void base<int>::foo() 
{
    std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;
}
template<> //or here
void base<int>::bar() {
    std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    base<int> i;
    i.foo();         // int
    i.bar();         // bar
}
```

In both places where `template<>` occurs, the output stays the same whether I include, either, both or neither:

```
test1
test2
```

I know that once a template is specialized, `template<>` is no longer used. But I have not specialized it for `int`, I've just implemented member functions for it. What does `template<>` do in this situation, and what is the difference in the code? I thought that `template<>` was necessary in this situation.

I'm using VS2019 for reference

Comment: There are many Q/A sets here on Stack Overflow that discuss the difference between *explicit* (using the `template<>`) and *implicit* (omitting it) *template function specialization* rules and syntax (just search for those terms). Alas, my grasp of the matter is insufficient to offer more than this!

Comment: I'd say MSVC is wrong for accepting the code without `template<>`. Neither GCC nor Clang do.

Comment: @walnut so this is confirmed a bug or extension, similar to the linked answer?

Comment: @ColinHicks I don't know. I was just searching for a duplicate. My previous comment is based purely on intuition.

Comment: After reading the relevant standard passage,  I agree with the linked question's answer that this is ill-formed and that the compiler should give a diagnostic. Given that it seems to have been in Visual C++ for so long, it might be intentional, though. (However, `/permissive-` does not cause a compilation error either.) I don't know whether or where a public MSVC issue list can be found, so I can't tell you whether it is considered confirmed bug.